# Token based authentication in grpc failing with bad gRPC response

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc, grpc-c#

I have created a service(on cloud) in ASP.NetCore whose endpoint is lets say "x". I added `services.AddGrpc()` in ConfigureServices and

```
   app.UseRouting();
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
       endpoints.MapGrpcService<GrpcServiceController>();
   });
```

in Configure method of the service Startup file.

I have not given any Authorization in GrpcServiceController as of now.

My client code(running from local machine) looks like this -

```
ChannelBase channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("<endpoint mentioned above for GRPC service = x>");
var ocrServiceClient = new OcrServiceClient(channel);
```

Upon calling from client -

```
await this.ocrServiceClient.HealthCheckAsync(new HealthCheckRequest());
```

the calls are failing with the error message -

```
{"Status(StatusCode=\"Unavailable\", Detail=\"Bad gRPC response. HTTP status code: 503\")"}
```

Any help on how to resolve the above issue ?

Comment: To confirm: you're not using token authentication (the server isn't expecting a token; the client isn't providing a token)? A simple next step would be to try a known-working|good client such as [gRPCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) to curl the endpoint from the server itself and then remotely to confirm that the Server is unavailable (503). What is the format of the endpoint? Are you include a scheme (`grpc://`, `https://`?)? Are you including a port?

Comment: @DazWilkin I am using https:// and using the port 3032